# Mysql Like Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Quick question: How do I mysqli_escape_string a variable enclosed in a like clause?

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%". %s . "%'"
```

or

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like '%"."%s"."%'"
```

don't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Or, if you want to avoid having to deal with escaping entirely, you should use parameters: SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ?, where the first parameter has value "%$search%" or the like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["terms"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%".$value."%'";
```

Or you could acheive this with sprintf like this:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%s'", "%".$value."%");
```

Comment: Hm let me check that out real quick -- I've been accustomed to sprintf("SELECT ", mysqli_escape_string($link, $var))

Comment: I fixed it to work using your method, but was unable to make it work with sprintf